# Java Spring Boot throwing following exception

Tags: spring-test

When I am using `@EnableAuthorizationServer` it is showing exception like 
create annotation `@EnableAuthorizationServer` and also showing exceptions at `import` statements like:

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.UserApprovalHandler;
```

Comment: import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer; (showing exception at this line)

Comment: hi Santhosh which boot version you are using and what exception you are getting can you please paste the exception stack trace along with your dependency chart

Comment: Also try adding

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Thanks Pradeep I will verify

Comment: Please update me if it works

Comment: i will tell if it works